# Robocopy mirror erasing files from excluded directory

Tags: windows, robocopy

I'm using robocopy (v 5.1.10.1027) to transfer files to my dev server through a network share. I'm using the `/MIR` option to make sure extra files get removed in case I rename something. There are several directories which I'm excluding since I have other processes to move them from different sources or at different times. Excluding those directories works most of the time except for one, where it lists it in the Excluded Directories, but then proceeds to remove all files from that directory.

My robocopy command looks like this:

```
robocopy . \\myserver.com\dev$ /MIR /XA:HR /XD assets /XD bin /XD ektsyncstatus /XD uploadedfiles /XD uploadedimages /XD privateassets /XD Campaign\Resources /XD InternalTools /XD ITS /XD postal /XD workarea /XD VideoPlayer /XD "XmlFiles\ITS" /XD ".*" /XF ".*" /XD "_*" /XF "*.config" /XF ekdavlog.txt /XF "uploadedfiles*.*" /XF "*.bak"
```

And the directory which it doesn't exclude is `Campaign\Resources`. Changing the order of excluded directories doesn't work.

Edit: It's doing this with our without quotes around it, and the other example of a subdirectory `"XmlFiles\ITS"` is being left alone.

The log is too long to fit into the question: https://gist.github.com/5thWall/d50afc102a09bdbf4235

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in quotes, similar to how the "XmlFiles\ITS" path is done?

Comment: ^ this. And can you test if "XmlFiles\ITS" is really working? Maybe by putting some test files into it and retry your command

Comment: XmlFiles\ITS is being left alone and I've tried it with or without quotes. If you'd like I can post the robocopy log.

Comment: And remove all those `/XD`'s. Just one is sufficient with a space between the dirs to exclude. Like `ROBOCOPY /XD DIR1 DIR2 DIR3`. And you can use `/L` for testing. It shows what it would be copying without really doing it. What version of robocopy are you using?

Comment: @Rik using v5.1.10.1027 (according to the properties on robocopy.exe, unless there's a better way to check that, it doesn't show up with `/?`) and noted about all the `/XD`s, though it doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: That's `XP027` according to wikipedia. You could try to debug this by only giving one exclude directory. `robocopy . \\myserver.com\dev$ /L /MIR /XA:HR /XD "Campaign\Resources"` (with `/L` for testing). I have read that "multipart"-paths sometimes give trouble. You could also try specifying the complete path. (some have done this with mixed results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a little test and can confirm that using "multipart"-paths with /XD in version XP027 is quite faulty.

Only if i included the complete path to the directory to be excluded it worked.

Perhaps you could try a newer version of Robocopy.

Comment: I end up adding the complete path for that entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in quotes, similar to how the "XmlFiles\ITS" path is done in your example.